# SqlAlchemy: get object instance state

Tags: sqlalchemy

This: [Intro to object states](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html?highlight=instance%20state#quickie-intro-to-object-states) lists the four permutations of presence-in-DB/presence-in-session:

```
transient, pending, persistent & detached
```

Is there any way of querying a given object to return which of the four states the object is in?

I tried rooting around in `_sa_instance_state` but couldn't find anything relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Better use [Inspection API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
state = inspect(obj)

# Booleans
state.transient
state.pending
state.detached
state.persistent
```

Comment: Note that `state.deleted` is only updated after a `Session.flush()` actually removes the record from the database. Before `flush()`, it seems that the only way to check whether `Session.delete()` has been called on the object is to [look for it in Session.deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20963631/648162) as @Erik49 suggests.

Comment: does this `def state(object): return inspect(object)` do the same?

Answer (score 30):

[Update: This answer is for versions before 0.8]

Found it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/5d5e8b2f2b796b45/a5f304ddf34abc69?show_docid=a5f304ddf34abc69):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import object_session 
from sqlalchemy.orm.util import has_identity 

# transient: 
object_session(obj) is None and not has_identity(obj) 
# pending: 
object_session(obj) is not None and not has_identity(obj) 
# detached: 
object_session(obj) is None and has_identity(obj) 
# persistent: 
object_session(obj) is not None and has_identity(obj)
```

Comment: This is definitely not the most obvious way! I think the code is more readable if you use `inspect(obj)` as [shown above by @kolypto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427235/648162).

Comment: Thanks @qris - have changed accepted answer. Question was asked before inspect system was introduced.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is [object_state](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.util.object_state), retuning an [InstanceState](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.util import object_state

state = object_state(obj)
# here are the four states:
state.transient  # !session & !identity_key
state.pending    #  session & !identity_key
state.persistent #  session &  identity_key
state.detached   # !session &  identity_key
# and low-level attrs
state.identity_key
state.has_identity # bool(identity_key)
state.session
```

Comment: Looks like these properties were added in SQLA 0.8

Answer (score 2):

another option, which lists ALL objects in particular states within a session:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#session-attributes

```
# pending objects recently added to the Session
session.new

# persistent objects which currently have changes detected
# (this collection is now created on the fly each time the property is called)
session.dirty

# persistent objects that have been marked as deleted via session.delete(obj)
session.deleted

# dictionary of all persistent objects, keyed on their
# identity key
session.identity_map
```

Comment: Note that `session.deleted` contains the object only between `delete()` and `flush()`, while `inspect(object).deleted` returns True only after  `flush()`, so these are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if an object has been **removed** you can use [was_deleted](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.InstanceState.was_deleted)

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect
 
inspect(object).was_deleted
```