# Deleting an object from an SQLAlchemy session before it's been persisted

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My application allows users to create and delete `Site` objects. I have implemented this using `session.add()` and `session.delete()`. I then have 'Save' and 'Reset' buttons that call `session.commit()` and `session.rollback()`.

If I add a new `Site`, then save/commit it, and then delete it, everything goes OK. However, if I try to remove an object from the session before it's been saved, I get a 'not persisted' error.

Code:

```
self.newSite = Site('foo')
self.session.add(self.newSite)
print self.session.new
self.session.delete(self.newSite)
```

Output:

```
IdentitySet([<Site('foo')>])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.1.2011071313\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 744, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.1.2011071313\pysrc\pydevd_vars.py", line 375, in evaluateExpression
    result = eval(compiled, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1245, in delete
    mapperutil.state_str(state))
InvalidRequestError: Instance '<Site at 0x1ed5fb0>' is not persisted
```

I understand what's happening here, but I'm not sure what I should be doing instead.

Is there some other method of removing a not-yet-persisted object from a session? Or should I be calling `session.flush()` before attempting a deletion, in case the object I want to delete hasn't been flushed yet?

If it's the latter, how come `session.query()` auto-flushes (ensuring that pending objects show up in the query results), but `session.delete()` doesn't (which would ensure that pending objects can be deleted without error).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can `Session.expunge()` it.    I think the rationale with `delete()` being that way is, it worries you're not keeping track of things if you send it a pending.     But I can see the other side of the story on that, I'll think about it.   Basically the state implied by `delete()` includes some assumptions of persistence but they're probably not as significant as I'm thinking.   An "expunge or delete" method then comes to mind, which is funny that's basically the "save or update" we originally copied from Hibernate, which just became "add".   "add" can do the transitions of transient->pending as well as detached->persistent - would a potential "remove()" do both pending->transient and persistent->deleted ?   too bad the scoped session already has "remove()"....

`Session.query()` autoflushes because it's about to go out to the database to emit some SQL to get some rows; so whatever you have locally needs to go out first.   `delete()` just marks the state of an object so there's no need to invoke any SQL.    If we wanted `delete()` to work on a pending, we'd just change that assertion.

Interestingly, if you `rollback()` the session, whatever you've `add()`'ed within that session, whether or not it got flushed, is expunged.

Comment: I agree with Mike that `delete` could be more forgiving. However, current situation is much simplified - there could be other related objects which were explicitely or implicitely (via relations) added to the same session and not commited. Therefore, IMO, the cleanest way is to do a `rollback()` on the session.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. So when the delete button is clicked, what should the logic be? Something like `try: session.delete(foo); except InvalidRequestError: session.expunge(foo)`? Or, as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3897845/665488), maybe: `if has_identity(foo): session.delete(foo); else: session.expunge(foo)`?

Comment: I'd probably say "if object in session.new: expunge else: delete"