# How to rollback changes in one instance using SqlAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

I have some instance of ORM class.

```
session = Session()
elems = session.query(Class)
cur_elem = elems.filter(Class.id == 1).first()
cur_elem.field = "NewValue"
```

How i can reject this change (or any other changes) **only for that** object before commit?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8306506/2144390

Comment: have use tried rollback? like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234206/4935275